# delete single row in grid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I need to delete a single row from grid, but every time I click the delete button in grid, my whole database is deleted. please help me rectify my code thanks.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    gridbind();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("delete from registration where Id=" + lblid.Text + "", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

and gridbind function is:

```
private void gridbind()
{

    string sql = string.Empty;
    string id = this.txtid.Text;
    string gender = this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

    if (gender =="male" || gender == "female") 
        sql = "Select * from registration WHERE Id like '%" + id + "%' AND gender = '"+gender+"'";

    if (gender =="male" || gender == "female" && id == this.txtid.Text)
        sql = " Select * from registration Where Id like '%" + id + "%' ";

    if (gender == "all" && id == this.txtid.Text)
        sql = " Select * from registration Where Id like '%" + id + "%' ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);

    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: lblid.Text  where you set this text?

Comment: Why are you binding your datasource and **then** deleting the row?

Comment: Also, your if statements don't make sense.  `id == this.txtid.Text` will always evaluate to true, since id is initialized as `string id = this.txtid.Text;`.

Comment: In the real world you will have to write Stored Procedures i the DB for doing tasks like that please clean your code and write Sp's then check them before calling them from code.
here is a tutorial how to call Sp's from c# . check it out.
http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson07

Answer (score 0):

first you have to use findcontrol for the row label named "lblid".

second, bind at the end.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Label theGridRowLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("lblid");

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = 
           new SqlCommand ("delete from registration where Id=" + theGridRowLabel.Text, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    gridbind();
}
```